# Angular - Get component that provided service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

If a have a component providing it's own service:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user-list',
    templateUrl: './user-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./user-list.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    animations: fuseAnimations,
    providers: [
        TableSettingsService
    ]
})
export class UserListComponent {}
```

Can this `TableSettingsService` somehow get a reference of this component? I've tried

```
@Injectable()
export class TableSettingsService {
    constructor(
        persistentService: PersistentService,
        @Optional() @Self() persistentObject: UserListComponent
    ) {
        alert(!!persistentObject);
    }
}
```

What causes a circular dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get component that provided service

It is not the component that has provided the service. The service has been injected inside the component. Search to understand how dependency injection actually as a concept works. Then you will see why you can not achieve what you want.

You have used `providers` array in your component

```
providers: [
        TableSettingsService
    ]
```

So it is sure that `UserListComponent` will retrieve the service using the `ElementInjector` of `<user-list>` component.

Any children components of `UserListComponent` will also (if they not have their own providers array declaration for that service) retrieve the service from the  the `ElementInjector` of `<user-list>` component.

In any case the service is injected inside the angular component. Not the other way around. So the service does not hold any reference to the component that uses it.

Comment: Ah, ok! At this point the instance doesn't exist, yet! Thank you! So I'll need to find another way around. Can I get **anything** of the component who's injector created this service? Maybe the component type that caused the injector to be created? That'd be enough.